# How do you use the contents of a variable as the key in a key value pair Using Typescript Firebase Cloud Functions to Update Database

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, typescript-typings

I have been working with Firebase Cloud functions for a while now, using typescript. I updated the firebase CLI and Node and a few other things which seems to have inadvertently included my Typescript compiler. The new compiler must have depreciated some concepts, because now my Index.TS file throws errors which would have complied fine with the old compiler. In the spirit of keeping my code base up to date, I would like to get my old code compliant with the new paradigms, rather than just finding the old compiler.

One major issue I have right now is that to update the Firebase realtime database, I would do something like this:

```
const PRIMARY_REF = admin.database().ref('**Database/Path**');

const Num = 2; 
const updates = {};
updates["1"] = false;
updates[Num] = false;

return PRIMARY_REF.update(updates);
```

This would update the database at Primary_Ref with two key value pairs, in this specific case {"1":false} and {2:false}. Note the use of the contents of the const Num as the Key of the second pair.

This worked a few months ago, but now draws an error with the new compiler,  **TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"1"' can't be used to index type '{}'.  Property '1' does not exist on type '{}'.**

After some Googling, I find a different way to do (what I think is) the same thing.

```
const PRIMARY_REF = admin.database().ref('**Database/Path**');

const Num = 2;
const updates = {"1":false, Num:false};

return PRIMARY_REF.update(updates);
```

However, now my key value pairs in the database are {"1":false} and {"Num":false}, which was not what I wanted. Instead of using the value stored in const Num, it just uses the string const name. what is the proper way to do this in the most up to date Typescript compiler?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `updates` is defined at it's declaration. So when you assign `{}` to it, typescript think that this object will never have any values in it.

As example, look at the following code :

```
const Num = 2; 

const updates: {
    1?: false,
    [Num]?: false,
} = {};

updates["1"] = false;
updates[Num] = false;
```

Here we say to typescript that `updates` is an object having two optional keys named `1` and `something` that will worth `false`.

---

Depending on what you want to do, here are some example :

### 1 - Any key with any value

```
const Num = 2; 

const updates: {
    [key:string]: any,
} = {};

updates['1'] = false;
updates[Num] = false;
```

---

### 2 - Direct assignation with type infering

```
const Num = 2;
const updates = { '1': false, [Num]: false};
```

Use the `[]` to say that the name of the key is a variable.